# Python requests session keeps creating connection without reusing the connection

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following code:

```
protocol = "http"
if self.protocol == PROTOCOL_HTTPS:
  protocol = "https"
if self.session is None:
  self.session = Session()
  self.session.get(protocol+'://'+self.ip)
url = protocol+"://"+self.ip+requestURL
response = None
if requestType == GET_METHOD:
  response = self.session.get(url, headers=(header),stream=False)
elif requestType == POST_METHOD:
  response = self.session.post(url, payload, headers=(header), stream=False)
```

This code works but it opens too many connections to the device. I want only one connection to be opened in the session. I tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work. It is still creating more than 1 connection.

```
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=1, pool_maxsize=1)
self.session.mount('http://', adapter)
url = protocol+"://"+self.ip+requestURL
resp = self.session.get(url)
```

What am I doing wrong?

How do I ensure that only one connection is opened in the session?

Comment: Does the device support Keep-Alive? A session cannot reuse connections from the pool if the remote side closes them or doesn't support re-use.

Comment: Yes. The session created is not closed by the device. It accumulates and reaches the maximum no. of sessions it can hold and then fails for subsequent request(as max sessions reached).

Comment: It could be that the device is not correctly communicating that connections can be reused while at the same time not closing the connections. It rings a vague bell but I don't have time right now to investigate, sorry.

Comment: The circumstances of the (calling) code is not clear to me. First part with self. Second without, order etc.

Comment: Considering the behavior I'd guess it is starting a new request before finishes the previous one. The request is just released for reuse once all body data has been read.

Comment: @wenzul - Edited the code. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The device is communicating correctly as I have a java code where I am reusing the session.

Comment: @olivecoder - If thats the case how can I ensure that the previous request is closed?

Comment: Why are you using the `HTTPAdapter`? It would be sufficient to create a `Session` object which you can use for connecting sites...

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this, @Pradeep?

Comment: The issue was with my code trying to cache the connection. This code works fine. Sorry for posting the quesion!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an `HTTPAdapter` for one connection.
May just try

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> s.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
```

from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session

Comment: I uderstand that this will create one connection for this request. In my case I have many requests, which will create many connecions. 

Anyways, the issue was with my code trying to cache the connection. This code works fine. Sorry for posting the quesion.